# "No such file or directory" error with Boost Python

Tags: python, boost

I've installed boost python from ubuntu 9.04 repositories. I've successfully run
[Build a Simple Program Using Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost) from the tutorial, so I know that boost python is installed on my system.

However, the program below returns an error:

```
#include <string>

namespace { // Avoid cluttering the global namespace.

  // A couple of simple C++ functions that we want to expose to Python.
  std::string greet() { return "hello, world"; }
  int square(int number) { return number * number; }
}
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(getting_started1)
{
    // Add regular functions to the module.
    def("greet", greet);
    def("square", square);
}
```

I tried to execute the first step from the below two steps to create a shared library:

```
g++ -c -fPIC hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libhello.so -o libhello.so  hello.o
```

(Are these the right commands?)

The following is the complete error output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:8,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:75:24: error: patchlevel.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:78:2: error: #error Python 2.2 or higher is required for this version of Boost.Python.
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:142:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/cast.hpp:13,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args_fwd.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/base_type_traits.hpp:24: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/base_type_traits.hpp:24: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/python/base_type_traits.hpp:30: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/base_type_traits.hpp:30: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/python/base_type_traits.hpp:36: error: ‘PyMethodObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/base_type_traits.hpp:36: error: template argument 1 is invalid
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:11,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args_fwd.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/errors.hpp:51: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:13,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args_fwd.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/handle_fwd.hpp:12: error: expected type-specifier before ‘PyObject’
/usr/include/boost/python/handle_fwd.hpp:12: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘PyObject’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:14,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args_fwd.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp: In function ‘T* boost::python::incref(T*)’:
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp:16: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp: In function ‘T* boost::python::xincref(T*)’:
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp:23: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp: In function ‘void boost::python::decref(T*)’:
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp:30: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp: In function ‘void boost::python::xdecref(T*)’:
/usr/include/boost/python/refcount.hpp:36: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/args_fwd.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::python::handle<T>::handle(boost::python::detail::borrowed_reference_t*)’:
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:130: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:130: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:157: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:157: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:157: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/handle.hpp:256: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/args_fwd.hpp:26: error: template argument 1 is invalid
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:14,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:34: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
/usr/include/boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:41: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:45: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:21,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:21: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:23: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:30: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:34: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:43: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:44: error: ‘PyObject’ is neither function nor member function; cannot be declared friend
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:44: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:49: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ has not been declared
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::python::detail::wrapper_base::wrapper_base()’:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:46: error: class ‘boost::python::detail::wrapper_base’ does not have any field named ‘m_self’
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:61: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:71: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:77: error: variable or field ‘initialize_wrapper’ declared void
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:77: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:77: error: ‘self’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:77: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:77: error: ‘w’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:82: error: variable or field ‘initialize_wrapper’ declared void
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:82: error: ‘PyObject’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:82: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrapper_base.hpp:82: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:57,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:62,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:67,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:72,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:77,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:82,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:87,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:92,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:97,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:102,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:107,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:112,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:117,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:122,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:63,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:176: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:47,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:57,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:62,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:67,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:72,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:77,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:82,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:87,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:92,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
             from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
             from first.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:199: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
In file included from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:97,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:99,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
             from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
```

Answer (score 31):

add `#include <Python.h>` and compile with `-I/usr/include/python2.6` or whatever your Python version is.

Do not forget to link it with `-lpython2.6 -lboost_python`

Comment: Had the same problem and this fixed it for me. Just in case if anyone uses Debian aswell - squeeze has a python-dev and python2.6-dev package (cost me another 5 minutes of looking around for a fix ;)

Comment: in my  case, I had the same problem, it couldn't find pyconfig.h so I did 'g++ -shared -c -o greet.so -fPIC greet.cpp -lpython2.7 -lboostpython -I/usr/local/include/python2.7'

Answer (score 17):

Although it's quite late, but still, here's my answer:

Make sure you have the libboost-python-dev libraries installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are missing the Python headers (Python.h etc.). Make sure you insteall the -devel or -dev package for your version of Python through the operating system package manager. This should provide the header files...

[Edit: noticed you are on ubuntu so try `sudo aptitude install python-dev` ]

Comment: `sudo aptitude install python-dev` helped me!
I appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Building a big program by executing individual commands like that can quickly get very complicated. You can use a build system like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) to find the dependencies and sort out the compiler commands for you.

The minimal `CMakeLists.txt` to use CMake with a boost python project is this:

```
project (MyProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories (${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS python)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_library (
    mylibinterface SHARED  
    mylib.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (mylibinterface
    boost_python
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```