# Import Error on boost python hello program

Tags: python, boost

## include

```
using namespace boost::python;

struct World{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
    ;
}
```

Compile and build ok

```
~/boost$ g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c hello.cpp 
~/boost$ g++ -shared hello.o -o hello.so
```

But when import from python side, got error.

```
>>> import hello.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./hello.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
>>>
```

Answer (score 14):

Solved this via ["No such file or directory" error with Boost Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771063/help-needed-with-boost-python)

```
g++ -c -fPIC hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,hello.so -o hello.so  hello.o -lpython2.6 -lboost_python
```

did the trick for me. I hope this is as clear as possible as i was struggling with this for about half an hour now ;)

Answer (score 7):

same as other post here

```
g++ -c -fPIC hello.cpp -o hello.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,hello.so -o hello.so  hello.o -lpython2.6 -lboost_python
```

But i want to stress the importance of the position of "-lpython2.6 -lboost_python". If you put them in front of input files (hello.o), they will be somehow ignored (not linked to the final hello.so). This is at least true for g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5).

To be simple, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=496287 suggested:

```
  g++ <.cpp or .o file(s)> [LDFLAGS] [LIBS] -o [appname]
```

Comment: As I understand it, the reason for the link-order sensitivity is that the GNU `ld` compile-time linker is a one-pass linker: it picks up symbols to resolve from left-to-right on the command-line, and maintains a list of unresolved symbols, so if `hello.o` is at the end, it introduces new unresolved symbols (that are defined in `libpython2.6.so` and `libboost_python.so`), but they can't now be resolved because there's nothing *to the right* that defines those symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, I just saw this post:

> [help needed with boost python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771063/help-needed-with-boost-python)

and problem solved

Comment: So was the solution to add "-lpython2.6 -lboost_python" to the link line?  It is not completely clear to me what you learned from the other thread...

Comment: @ChristopherBruns Did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it turned out that I was missing a constructor on my class.

Comment: Just had the same error, this one was so bloody sneaky!! Thanks a bunch for this remark, it could have taken me days until I noticed this