# Error importing Boost Python module (function_impl_base9max_arityEv)

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to build a hello world C++ Python extension using boost-python.

I got the following source code from https://www.mantidproject.org/Boost_Python_Introduction:

```
 // test.cpp
 #include <iostream>
 #include <boost/python.hpp>


 void sayHello()
 {
   std::cout << "Hello, Python!\n";
 }

 BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)  // Name here must match the name of the final shared library, i.e. mantid.dll or mantid.so
 {
    boost::python::def("sayHello", &sayHello);
 }
```

However, when I try to compile using the following command:

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m test.cpp -c
g++ -shared test.o -o test.so -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/lib64/libboost_python3
```

This command compiles successfully the code and creates a library file test.so.

However, when I try to import the module in python3, I get the following error:

**ImportError: /home/yt/C++/test.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv**

The link [Import Error on boost python hello program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780003/import-error-on-boost-python-hello-program) seems to suggest the command
I used above would solve the problem by adding *-I/usr/include/python3.6m* and *-I/lib64/libboost_python3*, but it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

OS: Fedora 29 x86_64

Comment: I think your linker flags should be `-l` (lower-case L) not `-I` (upper-case I). Includes don't make sense on a link line, and the error you're getting is a result of missing linker symbols.

Comment: Thanks. However, doing **g++ -L/lib64 -shared test.o -o test.so -l python3.6 -l libboost_python3** results in the errors: **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.6
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_python3**

Comment: `-L` is for library paths, `-l` is for libraries themselves, and you typically omit the `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix. That would mean your flags should be something like `-lpython3.6 -lboost_python3`.

Comment: Check your /lib64 directory for boost_python3 library existance. In my case library name is libboost_python.so. But I built it from the source code and didn't install it to the system folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys!

The problem was the linker command. The correct one is:

**g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m test.cpp -c**

**g++ -L /lib64 -shared test.o -o test.so -lpython3.6m -lboost_python3**

Now it works on Fedora 29